# Implementing a selected unix path for a specific application (e.g. pytest)

Tags: unix, path, pytest

I have two versions of `pytest` installed, one locally in a directory in my home directory, and one that is installed in `/usr/local/bin`.

The version of pytest installed in the `/usr/local/bin` is 2.2.4 and I don't have sudo rights to upgrade it to the newer version, 2.3.4, but need some tests to run with 2.3.4.

Is there a way to redirect the path so that it always uses the `pytest` in my home directory over the `pytest` in the `/usr/local/bin` directory when I invoke pytest?

Because there is a need to run many tests, it would be more convenient to have a shortcut!

Comment: Whenever you want to execute something, you can indicate the binary handling it. Hence, you can do `/your/new/path/pytest /your/path/program`.

Comment: Very true, that's what I've been doing except it becomes repetitive and lengthy as I must execute pytest over and over...

Comment: If you do not have sudo to upgrade, the thing you could is to create an alias to make it easier: `alias pytest=/your/new/path/pytest` and add it in your ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a directory to your `$PATH` that contains the copy of `pytest` you would like to use. For example, place `pytest` in `~/bin` and add `~/bin` (or `$HOME/bin`) to your path:

```
PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
```

As indicated, place the new directory at the front of the path so that your copy of `pytest` (and whatever else you put in `~/bin`) will be found first.

Even better, put those two lines into `~/.profile` so that your `$PATH` will be updated every time you log in.